Woocommerce ho to change action for backorder button?
How to make the Formcraft contact form be called when clicking the pre-order button? (only pre-order products) Thank you!
Unfortunately I did not find any information in the wordpress CODEX on how I can influence the add to cart button via functions.php to change button link only for products on-backorder.

Nobody can guess things by magic: What is "Formcraft contact form"? Note that by default in WooCommerce, there is no a "pre-order button"… Are you using a related 3rd party plugin? Also, you will not find any information in the "WordPress CODEX" as this is related to WooCommerce… So try to clarify your question. Then you should better search and provide your own code attempt.

@LoicTheAztec I don't use 3rd party plugins. I just want to change the link on the "add to cart" button on products that have stock status is pre-order in the admin panel.

@Hamdallah thank you for your method, but woocommerce default button still adds products to cart, but it should not be happening in my case.
That what I could make by now:


// removing default woocommerce button only for on-backorder type of products

add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'remove_add_to_cart_onbackorder_products', 25, 2 );
              
function remove_add_to_cart_onbackorder_products( $add_to_cart_html, $product ) {
    
    if( $product->is_type('simple') && $product->is_on_backorder()) {
        return '';
    }
    return $add_to_cart_html;
    
}

// making forminator button to call pop-up preorder form 

function preorderbtn(){
    echo do_shortcode( '[button text="Pre-order" link="#checkprice" class="clickbutton"]' );
}

// calling button on-backorder products 

add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'pre_order_button_url', 10, 2); 
function pre_order_button_url($url, $product) { 
    if ($product->is_on_backorder()) { 
    preorderbtn();
    } 
    return $url; 
} 



This works only for product category pages. I still need make it for single product page.
This action for single product page - remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary')
doesn't let me replace default button to my own, as the place for button is getting invisible.

Please check this code
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'custom_pre_order_button', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_pre_order_button_single', 30);

function custom_pre_order_button($button, $product) {
    if ($product->is_on_backorder()) {
        $button = '<a href="#" class="button pre-order-button" onclick="openFormcraftForm()">Pre-order Now</a>';
    }
    return $button;
}

function custom_pre_order_button_single() {
    global $product;

    if ($product->is_on_backorder()) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
        echo '<a href="#" class="button pre-order-button" onclick="openFormcraftForm()">Pre-order Now</a>';
    }
}

function openFormcraftForm() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openFormcraftForm() {
            jQuery('#formcraft-form-id').trigger('click');
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}


Thanks for the help and the option provided, but this method adds another button, and I need to replace the link with the existing standard add to cart (pre-order) button.

Perhaps you can tell me how to change the link on the add to cart button, but only on those products that have availability - pre-order.

You can check the filters
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'pre_order_button_url', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'pre_order_button_text', 10, 2);
function pre_order_button_url($url, $product) {
if ($product->is_type('simple') && $product->is_on_backorder()) {
// Change the URL to your custom link
}
return $url;
}
function pre_order_button_text($text, $product) {
if ($product->is_type('simple') && $product->is_on_backorder()) {
// Change the text on the button,
}
return $text;
}
